# Shell script not working to append the text at end the hosts/file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo, ec2-userdata

Trying to  append a text at the end of the hosts file but not working through userdata .

Service_start.sh script will execute certain commands and also a shell script (hostnames.sh)  once server started. every script is working but not this hostnames.sh and in the output log it is showing as success. I can’t see IP and hostname in the /etc/hosts

If I run it manually then it is working

Service_start.sh file contains

```
  #!/bin/bash
#script to udate hostnames in hosts file

ip=`facter testip`
hostname=`facter testhostname`

sudo /bin/bash /opt/resources/hostnames.sh >> /opt/test.log
```

and  hostnames.sh file conatains

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to udate hostnames in hosts file

ip=`facter testip`
hostname=`facter testhostname`

echo " " >> /etc/hosts

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo SUCCESS
else
   echo FAIL
fi
echo "$ip $hostname" >> /etc/hosts

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo SUCCESS
else
   echo FAIL
fi
```

Comment: Relevant docs: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#update-etc-hosts

Comment: our system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True
manage_etc_hosts: True

Comment: Either that or dhcp is overwriting your hosts file.

Comment: Looks like dhcp is overwriting the hosts file. how can I overcome this issue? need to append the text to hostsfile at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the ` to "

```
ip="facter testip"
hostname="facter testhostname"
```

Comment: Above script is working fine if I run it manaully so no isses with the scrpit

Comment: oh sorry, so you're using the `facter` command? I'm unfamiliar with that command and thought you were just making strings.